# android: Check the existence of a file in the application

Tags: android, file

I have few html files in assets folder of my application. My application loads these files depending on the device language. When I check for the existance of the file it say does not exist, but when I load that file using browser.loadUrl(filename), it loads it fine.

Following code will help you to understand my problem:

```
 String filename="file:///android_asset/actualfilemname.html";  
 File f = new File(filename);  
 if(!f.exist){  
    filename = "file:///android_asset/newfile.html";[Everytime it loads this file even though I have actualfilename.html in the folder]  
 }  
 browser.loadUrl(filename);
```

[it loads the newfile.html but not actualfilename.html]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `File` for resources. You'll need to use the `AssetManager` for that.

(In the off-chance that `File` does handle resources, which I don't think it does, you'll have to convert the path to a `URI` first, for example using `URI.create()`. File(String) expects a path, not a URI.)

Answer (score 1):

Is this the exact code you are using? you probably want to be calling f.exists() not filename.exist().

Edit: try working with the [AssetManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html) instead of hard coding your file path. My best guess is that the file path you are using is not exactly how it supposed to be.