# Loading files within android

Tags: java, android, file, io, android-assets

Android seems to make life pretty easy for loading resources of certain types. Once I leave the beaten path a little bit, it seems less helpful. I can load in images, sounds and other objects from the assets folder if and only if they are of certain types. If I try to load a binary file of my own format, I get a less than helpful 'file not found' exception, even though listing the directory shows that it is clearly there.

I've tried using the following methods to read a binary file of a custom format from the assets directory:

```
File jfile = new File("file://android_asset/"+filename); //tried to get the URI of the assets folder
JarFile file = new JarFile("assets/"+filename); //tried assuming the assets folder is root
fd = am.openNonAssetFd( filename); //tried getting my file as an non asset in the assets folder (n.b. it is definitely there)
fs = am.open(filename, AssetManager.ACCESS_BUFFER); //tried loading it as an asset
```

I'm thinking that there's something fundamental about android file I/O that I don't understand yet. The documentation for asset management seems incomplete and there must be some reason for deliberately making this unintuitive (something to do with security?). So, what's the fool proof, canonical way of loading a binary file of my own format within an android app?

UPDATE:

I tried file:///android_asset/ but still no joy.

```
String fullfilename = "file:///android_asset/"+filename;
File jfile = new File(fullfilename);
if (jfile.exists())
{
    return new FileInputStream(jfile);
}
else
{
return null;  //the file does exist but it always says it doesn't. 
}
```

Are there any permissions for the file or in the project manifest that I need?

Thanks

Comment: Define "binary file of my own format"? What are you talking about here?

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure how to be more specific. I have a file filled with data; in this case, a 3D model output from an editor I wrote. The format of the data is defined by myself - that is, the order of the bytes within the file are of a format I have chosen. 4 header bytes, material information, vertices as IEEE 4byte floats with position, colour, texture coordinates and so on. After that comes the polygon indices, animation data and so on. That's not so important though - what's important is that I get those bytes from the assets (or any other) folder and into memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to load a file from the Assets folder would be to use [AssetManager.open(String filename)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open%28java.lang.String%29) - this gives you back an `InputStream` which you can then wrap in a `BufferedInputStream` and otherwise call `read()` to get the bytes. This would work regardless of the file type. What kind of problems have you had with this approach specifically?

Comment: It returns a fileNotFoundException, even though it is actually there. I was wondering if I'd got the form of 'filename' right but I'm had no luck with all the permeations I've tried (file.ext, file:\\\file.ext, assets\file.ext file:\\\anroid_asset\file.ext etc)

Comment: I have used it simply with 'file.ext', i.e. am.open("file.ext");. Strange that it does not work for you in this situation! Try calling am.list(""); to get a list of files it thinks is in your assets folder.

Comment: Did that too (listed the files) and yes, it is strange. Maybe something odd is going on elsewhere in the program causing issues later on. Good to know that open(file) works for others though, that gives me something to aim for. Have you tried it with binary files.

Comment: Well, that now works. I'm not exactly sure what was different from when I initially tried 'open' but I didn't wrap it in a 'BufferedInputStream' so perhaps that's the key. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: I wrapped it in BufferedInputStream from the beginning. That was not the solution, read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have left out the slash as in

```
File jfile = new File("file:///android_asset/"+filename);
```

There's three forward slashes, not two. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It certainly looks correct but still no dice for me.

Comment: this seems to suggest that I can't load a file from the assets folder using new File(). If not, what's the alternative? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5981176/android-check-the-existence-of-a-file-in-the-application

Comment: This construction does not accept authorities and "android_asset" is such.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to uninistall the application, clean the project in Eclipse and run it again. The problem was Android couldn't find the new files I put in the asset folder.
I ended up reading this question so I hope this can be helpful to someone else.

Comment: No need to do all of this - just right click on "assets" tree item and select Refresh.