# My emulator doesn't load web page

Tags: android-webview

I have a problem related to webview.So i have created a file which is called index.html in my asstes folder as shown below

assets->www->index.html

this is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home/namiq/MyWorks/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.css" />
  <script src="/home/namiq/MyWorks/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="/home/namiq/MyWorks/jquery.mobile-1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>   
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is my MainActivity.java file

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.loadUrl("file:///home/namiq/MyWorks/examples/WebApp/assets/www/index.html");
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

it works fine in web browser.But when i run this in my emulator it says that

**The webpage at *file:///home/namiq/MyWorks/examples/WebApp/assets/www/index.html* might be temporary down or it may have moved permanently to a new address**

i have also added inretnet permission to my manifest.Can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are not trying to load a webpage, you are trying to load a file from your local machine that just happens to be a .html file.

Perhaps the mechanism used to access a local file (what you have) is different to that used to access a URL (the function you are using).

So put your test page (index.html) behind an actual server and pass that real URL to your code instead, rather then a path to a file.

Or just change the URL to a real URL (e.g. www.google.com) and see if it "works". If so, you can't load local files with that function.

Comment: I tried www.google.com it worked.With which function can i load local files?

Comment: You might as well just set up a local server, it'll be more realistic. I think this questions answers your new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972282/loading-files-within-android